# How to check the size of String pool in Java? or Do we have any tools to see the String pool to see the literals how many it has?

Tags: java

Just to know how many literals have been stored as per the current program which has only one literal but what If I do use toLowerCase() which returns another string, will this another string also get stored into the String pool? or it will not untill it gets assigned to a string variable?

Comment: It's not a literal, so no.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer but could you please get me the answer for the above question?

Comment: @SairamVinjamuri What part of 'no' didn't you understand?

Comment: you could respond (accepted) to the description which is after the question "How to check the size of String pool in Java? or Do we have any tools to see the String pool to see the literals how many it has?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> will this another string also get stored into the String pool?

No.

> or it will not untill it gets assigned to a string variable?

No. It won't get stored into the string pool at all, unless and until you call `intern()` on it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer but could you please get me the answer for the above question?

Comment: I have already provided answers for *both* of your questions. Unclear what you're asking for now.

Comment: You could respond to the description which is after the question "How to check the size of String pool in Java? or Do we have any tools to see the String pool to see the literals how many it has?"

Comment: I don't consider the questions in your title germane. They have nothing to do with the question expressed in the body of your post. The result of `toLowerCase()` doesn't go into the string pool, which is your actual question. You can use disassemblers, starting with `javap`, to see what's in the class file, but you're not going to find out what is in the string pool at runtime short of using a debugging API, and the information isn't of any practical use.

Comment: Ok, Do we have any tools to check the String Pool? as I just want to ensure the concept is true.